# Django: Show logging WITHOUT creating mysite.log file

Tags: python, django

I don't want the mysite.log file with my basic Django logging setup because the file typically ends up being massive and I don't use it.

How can I still have the error messages show up when running `python manage.py runserver` and in my Heroku logs WITHOUT having a mysite.log file created?

My logging settings in my settings.py file are below (note: these settings were copy & pasted from another stackoverflow post):

```
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'mysite.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Just do not use `file` as handler but the console.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a `console` handler that works with the `StreamHandler` instead:

```
LOGGING = {
    # …,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
```

This will then write to the standard output channel (`stdout`).

> the file typically ends up being massive and I don't use it.

You can also work with a [**`RotatingFileHandler`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler), this will prevent making huge files by only retaining the last *n* bytes:

```
LOGGING = {
    # …,
    'handlers': {
        'rotate': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'mysite.log',
            'maxBytes': 10*1024*1024
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['rotate'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers':['rotate'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!!!

Where do you learn about logging here?

Comment: @ZackPlauché: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/ and the logging package (which Django basically wraps): https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html